# how to refactor rust code to resolve borrow that reference parent in closure?

Tags: rust

```rust
trait OnUpdate {
    fn on_update(&mut self, x: &i32);
}
struct Foo {
    field: i32,
    cbs: Vec<Box<OnUpdate>>,
}

struct Bar {
    foos: Vec<Foo>,
}

impl Bar {
    fn call_foo_cb(&mut self) {
        self.foos
            .iter_mut()
            .for_each(|foo| foo.cbs.iter_mut().for_each(|cb| cb.on_update(&self.value(*foo)))) // compile error see below
            // .for_each(|foo| foo.cbs.iter_mut().for_each(|cb| cb.on_update(&10))) // works
    }

    fn value(&self, foo: Foo) -> i32 {
        foo.field + self.foos.len() as i32 // pretend some calculation based on the current foo and self
    }
}
```

The above code is to demonstrate my problem. I am new to rust and I am wondering what is the best way to refactor in idiomatic rust way.

Thanks in advance.

```
   --> src/lib.rs:348:23
    |
346 |         self.foos
    |         --------- mutable borrow occurs here
347 |             .iter_mut()
348 |             .for_each(|foo| foo.cbs.iter_mut().for_each(|cb| cb.on_update(&self.value(*foo))))
    |              -------- ^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here                   ---- second borrow occurs due to use of `self` in closure
    |              |
    |              mutable borrow later used by call
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easier for me to reason about this with for loops, so consider this equivalent:

```
for foo in &mut self.foos {
    for cb in &mut foo.cbs {
        cb.on_update(&self.value(foo));
    }
}
```

If the calculated value doesn't depend on `cb`, then it can be moved out of the loop:

```
for foo in &mut self.foos {
    let x = self.value(foo);
    for cb in &mut foo.cbs {
        cb.on_update(&x);
    }
}
```

And then, you can change out the mutable loop for one using indexes to avoid creating a mutable borrow until later:

```
for i in 0..self.foos.len() {
    let x = self.value(&self.foos[i]);
    for cb in &mut self.foos[i].cbs {
        cb.on_update(&x);
    }
}
```

---

This code assumes that the `value` function actually takes the `Foo` by reference since its not `Copy` or `Clone`.